# How to Create Dynamic Blocks using custom code in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

Can please help me how to create dynamic blocks using custom code.

Thanks for your help !!!

Regards,
Ram

Answer (score 1):

You should try googling about it:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/easy-way-to-create-blocks-programmatically

But also check out "Bean" module - it may be very useful for creating custom blocks:

https://www.drupal.org/project/bean

With that module you can create block type the same way you create content types and then just use template files to style output.